# Change Bootstrap Navbar items to "hamburger icon" at a certain width

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

So I've been trying to get my website's navbar item's to collapse into a "hamburger icon" after the browser window becomes thin enough.
Here's my html:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous">

<nav id="nav_bar" class="navbar navbar-custom">
  <a href="index.html" class="navbar-brand">Austin Okray</a>
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbar">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li><a href="ResumeStuff/Resume.pdf" target="_blank">My Resume</a></li>
        <li><a href="pythoncode.html">Python In-browser</a></li>
        <li><a href="fullcode.html">Download Full Code</a></li>
        <li class="dropdown">
          <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Internet Presence<span class="caret"></span></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="https://www.linkedin.com/in/austin-okray-7b578a106">LinkedIn</a></li>
            <li><a href="https://twitter.com/austin__okray">Twitter</a></li>
            <li><a href="https://github.com/aokray">Github</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-0mSbJDEHialfmuBBQP6A4Qrprq5OVfW37PRR3j5ELqxss1yVqOtnepnHVP9aJ7xS" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you use Bootstrap you can make two navbars. One that uses the hamburger to hide/show itself and one that's just plain in sight. Tag the hamburger nav with the class `.visible-xs-*` and the regular nav with the class `.hidden-xs`.

Some more information: http://getbootstrap.com/css/#responsive-utilities

Answer (score 0):

I've used [this example](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#navbar-default) as a sample. Please check this code:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous">

<nav id="nav_bar" class="navbar navbar-default">
  <div class="container-fluid">
   <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar-collapse" aria-expanded="false">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a href="index.html" class="navbar-brand">Austin Okray</a>
    </div>
    
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbar-collapse">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li><a href="ResumeStuff/Resume.pdf" target="_blank">My Resume</a></li>
        <li><a href="pythoncode.html">Python In-browser</a></li>
        <li><a href="fullcode.html">Download Full Code</a></li>
        <li class="dropdown">
          <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Internet Presence<span class="caret"></span></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="https://www.linkedin.com/in/austin-okray-7b578a106">LinkedIn</a></li>
            <li><a href="https://twitter.com/austin__okray">Twitter</a></li>
            <li><a href="https://github.com/aokray">Github</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-0mSbJDEHialfmuBBQP6A4Qrprq5OVfW37PRR3j5ELqxss1yVqOtnepnHVP9aJ7xS" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```